# Hosting static websites on Bitbucket for multiple repositories

Tags: bitbucket

Is there a way to host static websites on bitbucket cloud (https://bitbucket.org/) for your multiple repositories under one team or project?

Answer (score 0):

Found answer on https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Bitbucket/Website_Hosting

For hosting static content of multiple repositories, created repositories folders under the bitbucket.io repo (`https://bitbucket.org/<account-name>/<account-name>.bitbucket.io`) and put index.html in repo folders.

For example,

```
-root
   --repo-1
     --index.html
     --sample.js
     --sample.css
   --repo-2
     --
     --
   --repo-3
     --
     --
```